# SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'text' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, attributes

I have one method for get value from attribute

```
function GetValueFromAttributes(obj,i, key) {
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        return obj.childNodes[i].attributes.getNamedItem(key).text;
    } else {
        if (obj.childNodes[i].attributes) {
            var namedItem = obj.childNodes[i].attributes.getNamedItem(key.toLowerCase());
            if (namedItem) {
                return namedItem.value;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

in all browser work ok but in Internet Explorer 10 here

```
return obj.childNodes[i].attributes.getNamedItem(key).text;
```

give error:
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'text' of undefined or null reference

any ideas?

Comment: assuming that IE is a browser.

Comment: @Pietu1998 yes is 10 version of internet explorer

Comment: Don't use browser detection, but feature detection. Why are you hardcoding that line? It should be obvious that it might not work if any value in the chain is `undefined`.